# Postgresql9.3 query optimization

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, query-optimization

I am using postgresql 9.3 in my node.js application. In my database i have some 7lakhs records now. Also in my database i have json datatype column.

My query is as following:

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYSE select id_0, name_0, id_1, name_1, id_2, name_2, id_3, name_3, id_4, name_4, latitude, longitude, to_char(collecteddate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as collecteddate, key, value->>'xxxxx' as value from table where  
 CAST(value->'xxxxx'->> 'aaaaa' as INTEGER)BETWEEN 1  and  43722 and value->'PCA_2011'->> 'aaaaa' NOT LIKE ' ' and
 CAST(value->'xxxxx'->> 'bbbbb' as INTEGER)BETWEEN 1  and  100 and value->'xxxx'->> 'bbbbb' NOT LIKE ' '

 and leveltype = 'nnnn' and id_1= 'ww' and id_0 = 'uuu' and collecteddate = '2011-03-31';
```

This query will retrieve almost 1lakh records and takes  `3 secs` to be executed. I have created index for the json column and also the columns in where conditions. But i think its very long time to execute. Is there any way to reduce the execution time. I am new to this database optimization concepts, is there any optimization techniques to reduce my execution time to some milli seconds. Thanks in advance..

EDIT:

My index definition:

```
CREATE INDEX index_pop on table (id_0, id_1, collecteddate, leveltype, key, (value->'xxxxx'->>'aaaa'));
```

My Explain analyses result:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on table  (cost=1708.27..59956.46 rows=1 width=132) (actual time=880.576..5137.266 rows=93615 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (((id_0)::text = '356'::text) AND ((id_1)::text = '9'::text) AND (collecteddate = '2011-03-31'::date) AND ((leveltype)::text = 'pppp'::text))"
"  Filter: ((((value -> 'xxxx'::text) ->> 'aaaa'::text) !~~ ' '::text) AND (((value -> 'xxxxx'::text) ->> 'bbbb'::text) !~~ ' '::text) AND ((((value -> 'xxxxx'::text) ->> 'aaaaa'::text))::integer >= 1) AND ((((value -> 'PCA (...)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 4199"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_name  (cost=0.00..1708.27 rows=37856 width=0) (actual time=828.856..828.856 rows=97814 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (((id_0)::text = '356'::text) AND ((id_1)::text = '9'::text) AND (collecteddate = '2011-03-31'::date) AND ((leveltype)::text = 'ppppp'::text))"
"Total runtime: 5211.271 ms"
```

ALso 1 more thing: Bitmap Index Scan on index_name is different index other than in my where condition index, also y only 1 index is earched??

Comment: Please specify the relevant table and index definitions and give the output of explain analyze. However as you are parsing json and have 700.000 rows I don't expect it can be speeded up by much. You might want to experiment with the jsonb support in 9.4 which currently is in beta. Jsonb moves the parsing overhead to INSERT/UPDATE instead of having to reparse the JSON every SELECT and also supports GIN indexing.

Comment: lakh? And what about the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE? We now have to guess what's going on.